# In react navigation how can we replce drawer screen by stack screen where stack is in drawer? Not same screens (react native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

After successfull loging im moving to this drawer.

```
const SalesRepDrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <SalesRepDrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="SalesRepDashboardStack">
      <SalesRepDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="SalesRepDashboardStack"
        component={SalesRepDashboardStackNavigation}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Sales Rep Dashboard'
        }}
      />
      <SalesRepDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="Customers"
        component={CustomerListScreen}
      />
      <SalesRepDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="SalesOrderView"
        component={SalesOrderStackNavigation}
        options={{
          
        }}
      />
    </SalesRepDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

const SalesRepDashboardStackNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <SalesRepDashboardStackNavigator.Navigator key="test" headerMode="none" initialRouteName="SalesRepDashboard">
            <SalesRepDashboardStackNavigator.Screen
                name="SalesRepDashboard"
                component={SalesRepDashboardScreen}
            />
            <SalesRepDashboardStackNavigator.Screen
                name="CreateSalesOrder"
                component={CreateSalesOrderScreen}
            />
        </SalesRepDashboardStackNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};
```

then when i go to customer list screen and select a customer I want to move to create sales order screen and at the same time want to remove customer list route. I'm using react native with react navigation v5.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

In DrawerData component you will have to create a drawer item list (a custom component) and for navigation between the screens normally use the navigation.navigate('YOUR_SCREEN_NAME');

Add all your screens in the Stack.Navigator only. Drawer will have only the Home screen.

```
 /*Drawer data is custom drawer item list*/
    
 export function DrawerNav() {
          return (
            <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerData {...props} />}>
              <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          );
    }
    
    const RootStackScreen = () => { 
    
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="HomeScreen"
                component={DrawerNav}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="FirstScreen"
                component={FirstScreen}
              />
    
              <Stack.Screen
                name="SecondScreen"
                component={SecondScreen}
              />
     </Stack.Navigator>
    );
    
    }
```